# Lost user owner for Google maps API key

Tags: google-maps

We use an old Google maps API key in all our project and we can't recall who is the user who owns the key so we can modify the settings.
Is there any way to retrieve the user with the API key? 
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any idea who can be the owner? If so, try to ask in the [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:188851). I think it is possible to get a project number from Google support, but not the email address of the owner, because it is a Personal Identifiable Information and cannot be shared according to Privacy policy of Google.